# Query primary + local secondary indexes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I have "userID" (primary), "forum topic" (secondary-a), "subtopic" inside "topic" (secondary-b). I need to read/write/search subtopic text.

Can I query Primary (hash+range) + Secondary-A + Secondary-B key in single query to get specific results? Or I query Primary OR Secondary-a OR Secondary-b, so only 1 index choice?

Comment: no dynamodb experts here? anybody?

Comment: DynamoDB only lets you query one index at a time.  Other than that advice your question is a little confusing, could you draw out more specifics?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly!!!
you need to add the Indexes equals to secondary attribute you are creating.
Eg: if you have attribute "Secondary-A" and you should create index for it like  "Secondary-A-Index". note: your only able to query through the index what you created.